# Use old cpu fan/heatsink with slightly newer cpu

Tags: cpu, upgrade, fan, overheating, heatsink

I currently have a desktop computer with a Intel Core2 Duo E8400 CPU in it. The max TDP of it is 65W, and the CPU fan on it is an Intel E33681-001.

Now I just bought a replacement CPU, which is an Intel Core2 Quad Q8400, which has 4 cores instead of 2 and the max TDP is 95W.

However I only have the CPU, not the whole fan and stuff that comes with it. So I'm wondering if I could just use the same fan that was on my old CPU? I'm not quite sure what the TDP is so I don't know if using the same fan would work or cause any problems.

Comment: Are we talking about the stock Intel Heatsink/Fan or an aftermarket product?  If the two processors are on the same socket it does not really matter.  The stock fan didn't change between those two products which is the reason I asked.

Comment: This is only answerable in view of your usage of the computer and its physical design. So just try it and see.

Comment: @Ramhound its the stock intel fan. Its not an aftermarket product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the socket is the same - it is - then the same heatsink and fan should work.

[TDP = Thermal Design Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power)

but not really relevant in your case. The new CPU will draw more energy and get hotter than the old CPU so you should expect higher rpm but other than that nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Note for future visitors to this question: There's a chance, particularly when making major CPU upgrades (e.g. from a slower 2-core CPU to a faster 8-core CPU) that your old CPU cooler may not be able to keep up with the heat that the new CPU outputs, therefore it's always a good idea to get run some software for monitoring your CPU temperature so that *if it does* end up being an issue, you'll know about it (and presumably fix it), instead of accidentally cooking your new CPU till it fails.

Comment: @3D1T0R The change is from a Core2 Duo to a Core2 Quad LOL... Nothing so radical as to justify your warning. Besides there's no 8-core CPU that fits the sames socket of a Core2. But yes, monitoring is always a good idea. And CPUs throttle and shutdown way before being cooked anyway. Chill.

Comment: My warning wasn't so much for OP (as the change isn't too radical) but I always recommend that people monitor the temperature of a new CPU. I've seen too many people poorly apply the thermal paste, and I've even seen an instance where someone left a piece of the plastic packaging between the CPU and the heatsink (which went completely unnoticed until I used the PC and checked the CPU temp). Checking the CPU temperature after an upgrade is a good 'rule of thumb' that *everyone* who works on PCs should learn.